# Can I get a specific variable value from Gson converter without creating a bunch of models?

Tags: android, gson, retrofit2

If I have a response like that

```
{
    "data": {
        "main_category": {"user":{"name":"Ali","age":5}}
    }
}
```

the expected way to get my userModel >>

```
class User{
    String name;
    int age;
}

class MainCategory{
    User user;
}

class Data{
    MainCategory data;
}
```

Is there any way to get my user model directly? Like that

```
class Data{
    @SerializedName("data/main_category/user")
    User user;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Up Answers works to me
but i prefer to create just one more model on creating custom deserielizer for only one class
it's not generic case

Answer (score 0):

Create your custom deserializer:

```
class MyDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Content>
{
    @Override
    public Content deserialize(JsonElement je, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext jdc)
        throws JsonParseException
    {

        JsonElement data = je.getAsJsonObject().get("data");
        JsonElement mainCategory = je.getAsJsonObject().get("main_category");
        JsonElement user = je.getAsJsonObject().get("user");

        return new Gson().fromJson(user, User.class);
    }
}
```

Then create a gson builder like this:

```
Gson gson = 
    new GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapter(User.class, new MyDeserializer())
        .create();
```

And finally, in your retrofit instance assign the gson builder:

```
retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                    .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

Modifying data in such way may be not really a good idea due to data loss. Usually, (de)serialization libraries do not encourage you to do this. For such specific cases, in Gson, you must use custom (de)serializers implicitly if possible, or explicitly. However, you could implement it like this:

```java
final class UserResponse {

    @SerializedName("data")
    @JsonAdapter(UserSkippingJsonDeserializer.class)
    final User user = null;

}
```

The DTO above uses two annotations:

- `@SerializedName` -- to map a JSON property name to the field name
- `@JsonAdapter` -- to associate a specific JSON type adapter for this particular field only

```java
final class User {

    final String name = null;
    final int age = Integer.valueOf(0); /* disable javac inlining */

}
```

Now, you can create a template method `JsonDeserializer` to make a primitive remapping job:

```
abstract class SkippingJsonDeserializer<T>
        implements JsonDeserializer<T> {

    protected abstract JsonElement extract(JsonElement jsonElement);

    @Override
    public final T deserialize(final JsonElement jsonElement, final Type type, final JsonDeserializationContext context)
            throws JsonParseException {
        return context.deserialize(extract(jsonElement), type);
    }

}
```

And finally, define the `User` extraction rule:

```java
final class UserSkippingJsonDeserializer
        extends SkippingJsonDeserializer<User> {

    // Gson will instantiate it itself  
    private UserSkippingJsonDeserializer() {
    }

    @Override
    protected JsonElement extract(final JsonElement jsonElement) {
        return jsonElement.getAsJsonObject()
                .getAsJsonObject("main_category")
                .getAsJsonObject("user");
    }

}
```

Test it out:

```
final UserResponse userResponse = gson.fromJson(jsonReader, UserResponse.class);
System.out.println(userResponse.user.name);
```

will produce:

> Ali

If you want a more expressive implementation, you have to use something like JsonPath and implement a more complex JSON deserializer. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42510510/166589